# Error: "Access to the path '\\10.10.1.7\PrintPDF' is denied."

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to print PDF in my code but I am getting error:

> Access to the path '\10.10.1.7\PrintPDF' is denied.

Please help me. Here is web.config file:

```
    <add key="PrintPDFPath" value="\\10.10.1.7\PrintPDF" />
```

And in .aspx file:

```
    try
        {
            OffersCalculate objOffersCalculate = new OffersCalculate();
            objOffersCalculate.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            objOffersCalculate.Credentials = ServiceCredentials.NetCredentials();

            string strFilePath = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PrintPDFPath"] + objOffersCalculate.GetPostedAdvanceRcpt(Convert.ToString(Request["Id"]));

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.WriteFile(strFilePath);

            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: What is `\\10.10.1.7\PrintPDF` supposed to do? Is it a network location where you can write arbitrary files and which will generate PDF files out of that? If so, how does that work? Where will you obtain the resulting PDF file from? Why do you have `Response.WriteFile(strFilePath)`, do you understand that tries to read the file identified by `strFilePath` and write it to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your folder has permission to access that file other than admin user,
if not than make it accessible , but it is not wise thing to do, because it is violation of security.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you can access the path `\\10.10.1.7\PrintPDF` from outside of your code.

it seems to be a file system permission error.  no code issue.

Comment: sir,I can access this path.

Comment: you generate `strFilePath` on the fly. can you put the generated path that cause the error, here?

Comment: My path is in web.config file. which I stored in #strFilePath.

Comment: In this problem with Remote server  accessibility.But how can i solve it?

Answer (score -1):

Go to folder right click it and go to properties-->General--->Attribure--> change it to hidden

Comment: why someone has down voted this answer

Comment: Because it makes no sense at all to mark a folder hidden when the error is about permissions.